# Unity Input.location.Start doesnt enable location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, location

How to enable/ask to enable location service? Input.location.Start doesnt work, fine location permission are granted. Should I write java plugin?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Did you try the [sample code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html)? Which message did you get?

Comment: @Chuck by "doesn't work" I meant that user need to enable location manually. As I understood Input.location.Start() should start location service